# Why has there not been established any coherent measure of educative quality?

Tags: university, education, tuition

It seems nonsensical and backwards that university institutions can attract students by boasting with their brand value or exorbitant tuition fees rather than focusing on the actual educative quality their institution has to offer. Likewise, from the perspective of employers, it would be better to measure the actual education that potential employees have received, rather than have to hire supposedly smart Harvard graduates who then turn out to just be rich snobs.

Personally, I received my bachelor's from a "free" (tax-financed) university in Denmark, and then went on to study at LSE on a scholarship. If I had to pay for that master's degree, I'd be exponentially broke right now, and yet, I can honestly say that the education received in Denmark was more coherent and better structured, while LSE was more "read this, pass that exam, repeat", which is cool as well, but why are you demanding so much money then???

So my question is, why is there no established measure of the quality of the particular education offered at a particular institution? Is it because the powers that be have a vested interest in hiding the fact that high-tuition universitites with fancy latin mottos aren't actually more difficult to attend than average unis?

Comment: Ambiguity is a source of stability in fragile information systems.

Comment: Simplest answer: it's hard to measure the sort of quality that matters.

Comment: There might be a good question underneath the rant...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a rant, not a question.

Comment: You might like to read some about the field of education research.  Evaluating educational methods and outcomes in a consistent and meaningful way is extremely difficult, and AFAIK there is certainly no consensus on one single measure.

Comment: This is a highly meaningful and on-topic question. It shouldn't be closed. But I agree that it comes across as a rant and should be framed in a less opinionated way. Ideally the personal backstory should be replaced by OP's own preliminary research for the question.

Comment: @henning The ranting is what makes this question off-topic: it jumbles everything together. The title: why is there no "coherent measure of educative quality"? Implicit assumption of the question: what could such a thing even be? Who the hell are the "powers that be" that would decide what measure? How can university market themselves using their brand instead of "educative quality"? Why can university ask a huge tuition without such a measure? How come the education received at a free university felt better than the one at one with a big tuition? And so on. That's at least six questions.

Comment: @henning You are also very optimistic (to say the least) by talking about OP's "preliminary research".

Comment: To some extent, the quality of the education is on the shoulders of the student, and the grade issued by a professor may not be indicative of the student's skill. You will discover varying opinions upon that statement.

Comment: Of possible interest is this book I read a few years ago --- [**Academically Adrift: Limited Learning on College Campuses**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0226028569) by Richard Arum and Josipa Roksa.

Answer (score 5):

There have been numerous attempts to develop such “reductive” measures of educational quality, among others the *US News and World Report* rankings and the so-called Shanghai list.

The problem with these and other similar measures are that they reflect the specific aims and goals of the people who are creating the list. That is, there are no inherently unbiased and fully objective measures of educational quality and effectiveness.

Moreover, you can make the argument that even within a university, different departments can offer very different educational experiences as a result of class size, instructor quality, and other factors. So not only would you need an institutional ranking, you’d have to drill down to the department level, too, which is a very difficult endeavor.

Comment: Not to mention that academics are usually wary of such measures, because politicians will use them. The madness that is French higher education and research policy can be almost fully explained by the goal, stated explicitly by a former president: "let's get a French university in the top 10 of the Shanghai ranking, no matter what it means or costs"

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the "consumer" rankings mentioned by aeismail, there have been scholarly efforts such as the [National Survey of Student Engagement](http://nsse.indiana.edu/). U.S. accreditation practices offer self-evaluation, that are moving from being focused on inputs (library size, number of teachers, etc.) to outputs (schools figuring out how to show progress).

There are federal efforts that now provide baseline consumer reports, as a ["college scorecard"](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/). And in fact, [Harvard scores remarkably well](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/school/?166027-Harvard-University) as of 2018, with the average annual cost at $17,882 (due to generous need-based financial aid), a 6-year graduation rate of 98%, and the median earnings of graduates, 10 years out, of those who received federal financial aid, is $90,900.

The big conceptual difficulties in measurement are that students come in with all different preparation and goals (and there are not universal incoming measures about students--most colleges do not have very selective admissions criteria). Individual differences matter: some students would thrive at a small liberal arts college and learn poorly at a big state school, while other students might do the opposite.